# Полное расхождение массивов по ключу в PHP

Tags: php, массивы

Функция `array_diff_keys()` не совсем так работает. Нужно чтобы результатом было полное расхождение. Т.е. все элементы из `А` которые отсутствуют в `B` и все элементы из `B` которые отсутствуют в `А`.

Т.е. так:

```
array_merge(array_diff_keys($a, $b), array_diff_keys($b, $a));
```

Есть ли проще варианты ?

Comment: array_intersect

Comment: @Bloom при чем тут пересечение, если автор спрашивает про расхождение

Comment: проще вариантов не будет

Comment: Если хотите сэкономить несколько байт исходника, можно заменить `array_merge()` на `+` (в данном контексте)

Answer (score 1):

array_diff_keys эквивалент операции над множествами "разность"

```
A\B={x|(x in A) and (x non in B)}
```

Вы хотите операцию симметрической разности:

```
A delta B = {x|(x in A and x in B) and (x not in AB)}
```

Соответственно симметрическая разность так и реализуется:

```
A delta B=(A\B)+(B\A)
array_merge(array_diff_keys($a, $b), array_diff_keys($b, $a));
```

В PHP реализованы операции объединения (array_merge), пересечения (array_intersect) и разности (array_diff). Остальные операции над множествами реализуются через их композицию.

Если вы хотите получить только уникальные различия, то можно дополнительно обернуть в `array_unique`.

Comment: Мне кажется `array_unique()` как-то совсем не вяжется с вопросом

Comment: Если среди различий должны быть только уникальные, то дополнительно используйте array_unique.

Comment: Я к тому что в вопросе речь про ключи, а `array_unique()` - про значения